# compare two values with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check a value from two text fields with **JQuery**. I need to compare the dollar amounts to see if the new entered value is greater than the original amount. The outcome is not what I'm expecting at all. The first value is pre populated via PHP `OrigAMTVal` and the second value `amtTOrefundVal`is entered by the user. Here's the code:

```
$('#doREFUND').on("click", function() {
    var amtTOrefundVal = $('.amtTOrefund').val();
    var OrigAMTVal     = $('.CustomerOrderTotal').val();

    var doamtTOrefund  = parseInt(amtTOrefundVal).toFixed(2);
    var doOrigAMT      = parseInt(OrigAMTVal).toFixed(2);

    if( doamtTOrefund > doOrigAMT ) {    
        var balance = OrigAMTVal - doamtTOrefund;
        alert("BAD: $" + balance + " Over Limit");
    } else {
        var balance = OrigAMTVal - doamtTOrefund;
        alert("GOOD: $" + balance + " Left to Go");
    }
});
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dM2Fr/2/

I know I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do your values have leading 0s? You aren't specifying a radix when using *parseInt* so this might lead to weird results. Always use *parseInt(value,10)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toFixed` returns a string, just compare the values without that.

The problem is you are comparing strings and `"174 > "1000"` is true.

P.S. You should use `parseInt(value, 10)`.

Comment: Very good point, just realized thought about the toFixed myself... Definitely `typeof === "string"`

Comment: What about the decimal value? If I do 174.99 it does not use the .99 for the comparison?

Comment: @Monty: Ah, didn't think of that.  Change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`.

Comment: Almost, now what should I do to bring the .0s down to 2?

Comment: Nvm, I got it. I just put the .toFixed(2) on the printed variable. Thanks!